# Hide Audio Unit Extension For Third Party

Tags: cocoa, audiounit, avaudioengine

I have created Audio Unit Extension, which is visible to third party apps like garage band etc. I don't want to expose my app extension to third party and also I want to use it only inside my app. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You can build a custom Audio Unit subclass directly into your app, not as an extension.  Then it won't be visible as an extension, but will be usable by your app.